# How to display image in center across resolutions

Tags: android, xml, layout, alignment

I have a layout in which one of the  inside  doesn't come in center, It happens only in few resolution devices, whereas in few it comes perfectly in center. Below is code and screenshot

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/thank" android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
```

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/splash_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/thank" android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

        <com.teleca.sam.ui.Copyright
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use a single RelativeLayout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you are using a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

because your ImageView is in a RelativeLayout, you should use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

instead of

```
android:gravity="center"
```

in your ImageView tag

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout may be the reason for this. Try Linear Layout instead.